# Can't install Perl module Locale::gettext under Windows. (Library dependency problem.)

Tags: perl

Community!

I have a problem with the module Locale::gettext installation, used it for all my Perl projects.
Could you help me?

I can't install the module under Windows. What I did:

1. Downloaded and installed Citrus Perl.
2. Downloaded and installed libintl to C:\GnuWin32:

   https://altushost-swe.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/libintl/0.14.4/libintl-0.14.4.exe
3. Tried to install the Locale:gettext:

```
> cpan -i Locale::gettext

OR

C:\perl\cpan\build\Locale-gettext-1.07-LlB4BJ>perl Makefile.PL INC="-IC:\\GnuWin32\\include" LIBS="-LC:\\GnuWin32\\libs"
```

And it outputs:

```
checking for gettext... no
checking for gettext in -lintl... no
```

Folder C:\GnuWin32\lib\ contains libintl.def, libintl.dll.a, libintl.lib, libintl-bcc.lib.

Folder C:\GnuWin32\bin\ contains libintl3.dll.

Do you have any thoughts why this error happens?

Thank you.

Comment: You may have to first install the gettext C libraries. On Arch LInux, the Perl gettext package has a dependency on gettext.

Comment: I'll try, thank you.

Comment: With gettext installed the problem is the same :(

Comment: That `-I` is used for both the include and the lib dirs seems odd to me. Isn't it `-L` for the lib dir?

Comment: Just mistyped, thank you.

Comment: Maybe try Cygwin instead of GnuWin32? [Here](https://fossies.org/linux/gettext/INSTALL.windows) is installation instructions for Windows

Comment: If all my tries with native build will fail, I'll try Cygwin. Thank you. But native build is better I think.